# How to get the minimum of Sqrt[3x+1]+Sqrt[3y+1]+Sqrt[3z+1]?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, constraints, minimization

Let

```
f[x_,y_,z_] := Sqrt[3x+1]+Sqrt[3y+1]+Sqrt[3z+1]
```

I want to get the minimum of f for x>=0&&y>=0&&z>=0&&x+y+z==1 using mathematica.

PS: I do know how to get the minimum by math method:

```
Since 0<=x<=1,0<=y<=1,0<=z<=1, we have
0<=x^2<=x,0<=y^2<=y,0<=z^2<=z.
Hence,
3a+1 >= a^2 + 2a + 1 = (a+1)^2, where a in {x,y,z}.
Consequently,
f[x,y,z] >= x+1+y+1+z+1 = 4,
Where the equality holds if and only if (x==0&&y==0||z==1)||...
```

PS2: I expected the following code would work, but it did't.

```
Minimize[{f[x,y,z],x>=0&&y>=0&&z>=0&&x+y+z==1},{x,y,z}]
```

Actually, as Simon point out, it works ... The running time is longer than I expected and I closed it before Mahtematica show me the result.

Comment: huh?  only two viable options i see are x=y=z=(1/3), f(x,y,z)=3*sqrt(2) .... or x=y=0, z=1 leads to f(x,y,z)=1+1+sqrt(4)=1+1+2=4

Comment: @jon_darkstar minimum,not maximum

Comment: yea i caught that right afterwards =P.  but are the middle options even worth exploring?

Comment: Correct without constraints, but note that x + y + z = 1.  Need a Lagrange multiplier or two in there.

Comment: the partial derivative of f w.r.t any of three variables is obviously always decreasing, so you'd want to "consolidate" all of that x+y+z=1 constraint into one variable.   Legrange?  why?  i guess maybe if you needed a proof or wanted to generalize f in a weird way (generalizing constraints makes no differenece - replace x+y+z=1 with x+y+z=k and you still want one of them to be equal to k), but intuitively its pretty straightforward

Comment: Try the same with FindMinimum. It only finds local minima, but much faster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
In[1]:= f[x_,y_,z_]:=Sqrt[3x+1]+Sqrt[3y+1]+Sqrt[3z+1]
In[2]:= Minimize[{f[x,y,z],x>=0,y>=0,z>=0,x+y+z==1},{x,y,z}]
Out[2]= {4,{x->1,y->0,z->0}}
```

Note that the Documentation says "*Even if the same minimum is achieved at several points, only one is returned*" so you will have to impose the permutation symmetry of the problem yourself.

---

PS
You can turn this into a Lagrange Multiplier problem

```
In[3]:= Thread[D[f[x,y,z] - \[Lambda](x+y+z-1), {{x,y,z,\[Lambda]}}]==0];
        Reduce[Join[%,{x>=0,y>=0,z>=0}],{x,y,z,\[Lambda]},Reals]
        {f[x,y,z],D[f[x, y, z], {{x, y, z}, 2}]}/.ToRules[%]
Out[4]= x==1/3&&y==1/3&&z==1/3&&\[Lambda]==3/(2 Sqrt[2])
Out[5]= {3 Sqrt[2],{{-(9/(8 Sqrt[2])),0,0},{0,-(9/(8 Sqrt[2])),0},{0,0,-(9/(8 Sqrt[2]))}}}
```

and see that the only stationary point is the maximum at x=y=z=1/3. Thus the minimum must lie on the boundary. You can then use similar code but restricted to the boundary to eventually find the correct result.

Comment: Oh, thanks. That's what I want. Actually, I have tried that and it had been running more than 2 mius  before I forced close the program.

Comment: @Eastsun: It is quite slow -- It took about 30secs on my cheap hp laptop... The reduce code is much faster.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, this is a plot of the solution given by Simon:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := Sqrt[3 x + 1] + Sqrt[3 y + 1] + Sqrt[3 z + 1]
g1 = ContourPlot3D[f[x, y, z] == 4, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {x,y,z}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, ContourStyle -> {Blue, Opacity[0.5]}];
g2 = ContourPlot3D[ x + y + z == 1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {x,y,z}, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, ContourStyle -> {Green, Opacity[0.5]}];
Show[g1, g2, Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.05], Red, Point[{1, 0, 0}]}], ViewPoint -> {1.1`, -2.4`, 1.7`}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You say you aren't interested in the "math method" (I'm not sure what you have in mind when you say that, but it makes me think of minimization methods with Lagrange multipliers).  If that's correct, why do you bring Mathematica into the discussion?  What do you think it'll be using?

I'll have to assume that you mean numerical, computer solutions.  I'd start with linear programming and the simplex method.

Comment: I just want to know if there have any simple way, i.e. solved the problem in one or two lines.

Comment: linear programming / numerical would do it, but that deserves a more interesting function to optimize IMO